# Full list of tput options

Tags: man, documentation, tput

I wanted to hide the cursor, and I was aware of `tput` command. I did search its man page. On searching the Internet, I found

```
$ tput civis  # to hide the cursor
$ tput cnorm  # to bring back the cursor
```

These work perfectly, but these options are not mentioned anywhere in the man page.

Where are they officially documented?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`tput`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) command uses `terminfo` (from `man tput`):

> `tput [-Ttype] capname [parms ... ]`
>
> (…)
>
> For a complete list of capabilities and the `capname` associated with each, see terminfo(5).
>
> (…)
>
> `capname`
> indicates the capability from the terminfo database. When termcap support is compiled in, the termcap name for the capability is also accepted.

The `civis` and `cnorm` are documented in [`terminfo`'s man page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html):

```
   cursor_invisible              civis      vi        make cursor invisi‐
                                                      ble
   cursor_normal                 cnorm      ve        make cursor appear
                                                      normal (undo
                                                      civis/cvvis)
```

In general, when you don't know which man page describes a particular command, you can search for it. In this case, I found the above by running `man -K civis`.

Answer (score -1):

I was on a deep search to find this exact information myself and ran into this post. I left it there just in case I found something and I finally found it! This has all the information you asked about and more. It is very detailed with information on each of the options available with tput and a short explanation. Go down to the "Capabilities" section.

It's at the gnu.org web site, https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html

Comment: It's also available on your system with the command `man terminfo`

Comment: I had to do a lot of searching just to find a reference to terminfo and tput together. I am learning on my own and I had no idea that the two were related. I hardly ever found a reference with the two together mentioned on the same page. Most sites only give a little information on tput itself without going into any of the options other than say there are options. Most do not mention that tput and terminfo are related at all.

Comment: The `SEE ALSO` section at the end of each man page can be useful. The numbers in brackets denote the section number, eg `man 5 terminfo`. The number can be omitted except where there are otherwise multiple entries

Comment: By the way, if you're teaching yourself, welcome!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/460443)